# passing mixins to styled-component

Tags: css, material-ui, styled-components

I am trying to pass a mixin from Material UI to a styled-component. The issue is that I can't figure out a way to pass the mixin value to the styled-component without assigning it to to a css property. For example, this is not possible:

```
const Example = styled.div`
  ${p => p.theme.mixins.toolbar};
`;
```

Edit: The issue ended up being the semi-colon next to the closing '}'. I believe adding a semi colon makes the styled-component think that you are adding a normal property, not a mixin.

Comment: Any updates on this? Correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

You need to spread the mixins not calling it, like so:

```js
const Example = styled.div`
  ${props => ({ ...props.theme.mixins.toolbar })}
`;
```

Yet that will return style object, you might wanna convert the resulting object into css-compatible syntax as follows:

```js
const Example = styled.div`
  ${props => (Object.entries({ ...props.theme.mixins.toolbar }).reduce((styleString, [propName, propValue]) => {
      if (propName.indexOf('@') !== -1) {
        // iterate over media queries
        return `${styleString}${propName} { ${Object.entries(propValue).reduce((ss, [pn, pv]) => {
          pn = pn.replace(/([A-Z])/g, m => `-${m[0].toLowerCase()}`);
          return `${ss}${pn}:${pv+(Number.isInteger(pv) ? 'px' : '')};`;
        }, '')}; }`;
      }
      propName = propName.replace(/([A-Z])/g, matches => `-${matches[0].toLowerCase()}`); // convert camel-case properties into dash-splitted attributes
      return `${styleString}${propName}:${propValue+(Number.isInteger(propValue) ? 'px' : '')};`; // append css pixel unit to integer values
    }, ''))}
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I read your edit but deleting the semicolon didn't work for me. This worked:

```
import React from "react";
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import styled, { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";

const Content = styled.div`
  toolbar: ${props => props.theme.mixins.toolbar};
`;

const theme = createMuiTheme();

const Wrapper = props => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Content children={props.children} />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default Wrapper;
```

Answer (score 0):

I read this [documentation](https://mui.com/components/app-bar/), and very simple code:

```
const Offset = styled('div')(({ theme }) => theme.mixins.toolbar);

function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <AppBar position="fixed">
        <Toolbar>{/* content */}</Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Offset />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```